# Keras pretrained Xception model always gives the prediction 'sewing_machine'

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, pre-trained-model

I'm using Keras pretrained model 'Xception' to do image recognition. However, no matter what picture I give Xception, the predictions are always:

> Predicted: [[('n04179913', 'sewing_machine', 1.0), ('n15075141,
>   toilet_tissue', 0.0), ('n02317335', 'starfish', 0.0), ('n02389026,
>   sorrel', 0.0), ('n02364673', 'guinea_pig', 0.0)]]

Is there anything wrong with my code?

My code is:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.keras import applications as app
from tensorflow.contrib.keras import preprocessing as pp
import numpy as np

model = app.Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
img_path = 'test123.jpg'
img = pp.image.load_img(path=img_path, target_size=(299, 299))
x = pp.image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = app.xception.preprocess_input(x)

preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', app.xception.decode_predictions(preds))
```

Comment: Weird. Could you print out `x.max()` and `x.min()`?

Comment: This code works perfectly for me. Are you on the newest versions of keras and tf?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with TF 1.3.0. Changing `from tensorflow.contrib.keras import applications` into `from keras import applications` fixes the problem for me. Maybe there are some issues in the TF-keras code base. You can try to install keras instead of using it from TF.

Comment: @Yu-Yang This seems to be a bug of keras in tensorflow, I have changed the import statement to 'from keras import applications'  and everything works fine now. Thanks

Comment: @McLawrence I'm using the newest version of tensorflow on windows platform. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: Just in case someone really needs to use TF-Keras, this problem has already been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/17f26f81bfaf8ee03e330b98f4297cb754676c35). It's not yet included in the latest released TF 1.3.0 on pip, but the [nightly build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation) already has it.

Answer (score -1):

Normalize the image by x/255. just before predict function call
As per my understanding, Xception module is trained on normalized intensities. I faced the same problem. So, i normalized the pixel intensities by dividing them by 255. You can try the same. I hope it helps.